# how to reorder worksheet positions in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to rearrange the order of worksheets in an Excel workbook I'm creating in C#;  I would like the Product worksheet to appear 1st in the workbook.  I've tried "Move" but it's not being recognized.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
public static bool ExportReportToExcel(DataSet ds, string fileName, 
    DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    bool isSuccessful = false;

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating Excel File at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        // Save file after processing to local folder (in case 
        // network location is blocked, we will still have the file)
        if (File.Exists(fileName)) { File.Delete(fileName); }

        // create new workbook for the new source
        XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();

        // Set default font for workbook
        wb.Style.Font.FontName = "Arial";
        wb.Style.Font.FontSize = 8;

        List<Definition> definitions = GetDefinitions(ds.Tables[1]);

        IXLWorksheet ws = wb.AddWorksheet("Products");
        WriteHeaders(ws, ds, startDate, endDate, definitions);
        WriteTotals(ws, startDate, endDate);
        WriteDetails(ws, ds, startDate, endDate);

        IXLWorksheet defWS = Tools.AddDefinitionsWorksheet(wb, definitions, 
            "Product Report", 4, 60, false);
        WriteSourcesToDefinitions(defWS, ds);

        // save file
        wb.SaveAs(fileName);
        isSuccessful = true;                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        string logFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorLogFile"];
        Tools.LogToFile(logFileName, "ProductRpt", "Exception: " + ex.Message + 
            "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }

    return isSuccessful;
}
```

Comment: is this done using ClosedXML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Position property. Try adding

```
ws.Position = 1;
```

here is the reference: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Organizing%20Sheets&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried that but I had the syntax off.  Also it wouldn't work to change the position of ws.  I had to set the position of defWS = 2 and then it worked....

Comment: that is strange, but I have worked with ClosedXML before and it certainly has it quirks. The fact that assigning a position swaps worksheets seems a bit strange to me. It may be possible that ws does not have a position at that moment? hard to say exactly. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this function overload in `XLWorkbook` class:

```
    public IXLWorksheet AddWorksheet(String sheetName, Int32 position)
    {
        return Worksheets.Add(sheetName, position);
    }
```

As you can see you can pass the desired position to this function